# what does 참 mean in this case?? found in novel

Tags: vocabulary

세상에, 사막에, 그 마른 땅에 어떻게 벼락이 치는가에 대해 배웠고, 그걸 되새기고 있던 [[참이었다]]. 
I looked in the dictionary and none of them make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

역+참 is mean of 'road' or 'station'

역 = korean word,
참 = chinese word

In history, there is a limit to running away from the horse, so made '역참' (inn) made the horse rest in the middle.

But as time passed, the words changed
역참 -> 참 -> 역.

Being in (역)참 means somewhere on the way, so

~하던 참이었다 = i was doing something

※(reference)
Distance between 참 and 참 was 12~40Km. So 한참을 가다 means go for a long time

Sorry about bad english :(

Comment: Thank you for the long explanation. It makes much easier to remember it !

Answer (score 1):

From [Naver dictionary](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=36713800):

> (의존명사) 무엇을 하는 경우나 때.